# Web API Call is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

This is the first time I am using the Web API component in MVC 4. I just created a Web API project to manage a person details. I wrote a get function in Person Controller and called it from browser. The result is:

```
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebAPITest.Models">
    <Person>
        <Address>Addr</Address>
        <DOB>2013-05-04T00:00:00</DOB>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>Name</Name>
    </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

The URL is: `http://localhost:3802/api/Person`

Then I added a new MVC basic project to the solution and tried to call the Web API from the view page.
The code in view page is :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3802/api/Person",
            type: "Get",
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $("<tr></tr><td></td>" + data[i].Name + "</td><td></td>" + data[i].Address + "</td><td></td>" + data[i].DOB + "</td></tr>").appendTo("#tbPerson");                   
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) { alert("Error"); }
        });
    });    
</script>
<h2>Index</h2>
<table id="tbPerson">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>DOB</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But I am getting the alert box showing the Error. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Make sure the development server is working at 3802 port.

Comment: Open an inspector in chrome or firebug and look at the Request and Response.  Just because it is giving you the error in your Ajax request doesn't mean that you shouldn't be getting the error.  There might be an internal server 500 error or there might be some other issue but this might get you more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you added a new MVC project, it will run in a port other than 3802. So, the page URI will be something like `http://localhost:<someport>/home/index`. If JavaScript from this page calls the URI of your API endpoint, which is `http://localhost:3802/api/Person`, the request becomes a cross-origin request and browser does not allow it. For more info, take a look at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api. There is a great MSDN article by Brock Allen on this topic - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `url: "http://localhost:3802/api/Person"` 
to 
**url: "/api/Person"**